Asus ROG Wireless keyboard logging of KDE after waking keyboard from sleep (battery saving mode)
First this is not so much a question but a solution I came up, and wanted to share if anyone is facing this issue since I didn't find anything online except one guy who gave up. Also I asked ASUS for some assistance and they tolled me to install windows :D.
I got a ASUS ROG STRIC SCOPE NX wireless keyboard, and I have a bug where when the keyboard is in sleep mode (to save battery) and I press a button to wake it up it loged me out of KDE and shows me the logging screen. This is happening on my personal PC and on my work laptop both have Kubuntu 22.04 (also tried with Kubuntu 23.10)
So after trying to disable all the sleep button cmds from settings and disabling from /etc/systemd/logind.conf signals to no avail I noticed in xev that when this happens this message is spammed :
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x400001,
    root 0x1f1, subw 0x0, time 39552, (-385,-158), root:(1446,1215),
    state 0x10, keycode 151 (keysym 0x0, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

So for some reason the keyboard is sending strange signals.
When running xinput also I noticed there are some strange keyboards 15 and 12:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Keyboard            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUSTeK ROG STRIX SCOPE NX WIRELESS DELUXE Mouse  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUSTeK ROG STRIX SCOPE NX WIRELESS DELUXE        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUSTeK ROG STRIX SCOPE NX WIRELESS DELUXE Consumer Control       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G560 Gaming Speaker Consumer Control     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G560 Gaming Speaker              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Keyboard            id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
∼ ASUSTeK ROG STRIX SCOPE NX WIRELESS DELUXE    id=15   [floating slave]
∼ ASUSTeK ROG STRIX SCOPE NX WIRELESS DELUXE System Control     id=12   [floating slave]

And after disabling them with xinput disable 15 and xinput disable 12 the issue is gone.
So my solution is to write a 'script' :) with two lines :
#!/bin/bash

xinput disable 12
xinput disable 15

And create a simple .desktop entry in ~/.config/autostart that executes the cmds when KDE starts:
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=~/scripts/keyboard-fix.sh # The location for the script (don't forget chmod +x script) 
Icon=dialog-scripts
Name[en_US]=Unlock KeePassXC database
Name=Unlock KeePassXC database
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-KDE-AutostartScript=true
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false

After disabling these inputs I haven't found any missing functions on the keyboard (all media and special keys are functioning).
Hope this is helpful to someone and if anyone has any better solutions please share :).
